# 1C-Bitrix не отображаются настройки параметров компонента

Tags: битрикс, компоненты

Есть некоторый компонент (скорее всего самописный), у которого не отображаются параметры по клику на шестеренку в режиме правки или  через админ панель или другими способами.

```
<?$APPLICATION->IncludeComponent(
    "vii:ser.my", 
    "new2021", 
    array(
        "IBLOCK_TYPE" => "services",
        "IBLOCK_ID" => "34",
        "SECTION_ID" => $_REQUEST["SECTION_ID"],
        "SECTION_CODE" => "",
        "COUNT_ELEMENTS" => "Y",
        "TOP_DEPTH" => "2",
        "SECTION_FIELDS" => array(
            0 => "",
            1 => "",
        ),
        "SECTION_USER_FIELDS" => array(
            0 => "",
            1 => "",
        ),
        "SECTION_URL" => "",
        "CACHE_TYPE" => "A",
        "CACHE_TIME" => "36000000",
        "CACHE_GROUPS" => "Y",
        "ADD_SECTIONS_CHAIN" => "Y"
    ),
    false
);?>
```

Можно ли в блок конфигурации компонента в шаблоне добавить в раздел настройка списка поля и свойства которые должны быть активны.
Такие строки:

```
"LIST_FIELD_CODE" => array(
            0 => "PREVIEW_TEXT",
            1 => "PREVIEW_PICTURE",
            2 => "",
        ),
```

и такие:

```
"LIST_PROPERTY_CODE" => array(
            0 => "PICTURE_SERVICE",
            
        ),
```

Пробовал добавить эти строки заранее прописав значения соответствующим полям и свойству в настройке элемента, но print_r не отображются ни поля, ни свойства.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Компонент самописный. В папке с компонентом (не шаблоном!) должен быть файл .parameters.php. Там описываются необходимые настройки компонента.

В Вашем случае думаю проще использовать result_modifier.php в папке с шаблоном (создать самим, если отсутствует) и уже там достать все, что душе угодно.

Comment: Пробовал скопировать в parameters.php  моего компонента из компонента новости ( там задаются активные поля и свойства) не получилось, видимо еще какие-то файлы нужны,

Comment: Проблему описал в другом вопросе. https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1233279/1%d0%a1-bitrix-%d0%b2-parameters-php-%d1%81%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%be%d0%bf%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%be-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bc%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bd%d0%b5%d0%bd%d1%82%d0%b0-%d0%b4%d0%be%d0%b1%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8f-%d0%b8-%d1%81%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b9%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b2%d0%b0-%d0%b8%d0%b7-pa