# 1С-bitrix в parameters.php самописного компонента добавить поля и свойства из parameters.php компонента новости

Tags: битрикс, компоненты, параметры

Есть самописный компонент, у которого не доступны настройки параметров компонента. Поэтому не могу сделать  чтобы значение этого свойства выводилось на странице.
Нужно  в parameters.php самописного компонента добавить поля и свойства из parameters.php компонента новости, а именно раздел настроек списка. Пробовал тупо скопировать из одного в другой. не получилось.
Нужно чтобы было так:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

а получилось так:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Еще какие-то файлы нужны?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Смотри внимательно в .parameters.php

```
$arComponentParameters = array(
    'GROUPS' => array(),
    'PARAMETERS' => array()
);
```

В блоке групп должны отображатся сексии настроек. Далее, в блоке параметров:

```
'IBLOCK_TYPE' => array(
        'PARENT' => 'BASE',
        'NAME' => GetMessage('IBLOCK_TYPE'),
        'TYPE' => 'LIST',
        'VALUES' => $arIBlockType,
        'REFRESH' => 'Y',
    )
```

PARENT указывает на секцию, в которой должен отображаться настраиваемый параметр.

Ну и не забываем про языковые файлы.

Comment: Хорошо это я понял, только не могу найти, как выглядит блок параметров отвечающий за показ свойств и полей. Копаю еще в сторону альтернативного пути решения проблемы, которую попытался сформулировать в вопросе https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1233298